Differences in XML output between SQL Server Management Studio and sqlcmd
I have the following query which is used to export data in XML format. I was using the same query for years on SQL Server 2008.
Recently I had to upgrade to SQL Server 2019. Since then, while the query produces a valid XML if I run in SQL Server Management Studio, it exports a corrupted XML file, with validation errors if if run it using SQLCMD (I use SQLCMD to automate some tasks)
:XML ON
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

USE toll;

SELECT 
    ( 
        SELECT     
            PRODUCTSTABLE.CODE2 COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS SKU, 
            PRODUCTSTABLE.NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS PRODUCT_NAME, 
            dbo.MTRMARK.NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS BRAND, 
            dbo.MTRMODEL.NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS GENDER, 
            dbo.MTRSEASON.CODE COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS SEASON,
            ISNULL(dbo.utbl01.NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS,'') AS COLOR, 
            PRODUCTSTABLE.CODE COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS SOFT1ID,
            /* START VARIATIONS */
            (
                SELECT 
                    dbo.MTRL.CODE2 + '-' + dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS VARIATION_SKU, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1NAME COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS SIZE, 
                    CAST(CASE WHEN SUM(dbo.CCCMLFINF.NEWREST) > 0 THEN SUM(dbo.CCCMLFINF.NEWREST) ELSE 0 END AS INT) AS STOCK, 
                    LTRIM(STR(dbo.MTRL.PRICEW, 10, 2)) AS REGULAR_PRICE, 
                    dbo.MTRL.CODE2 COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS PARENT_SKU, 
                    dbo.CDIMLINES.NAME1 COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS CDIM, 
                    dbo.MTRL.MTRL AS MTRLID, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIMLINES1 AS LINENUM1, 
                    CASE WHEN dbo.MTRL.PRICER = dbo.MTRL.PRICEW THEN '' ELSE LTRIM(STR(dbo.MTRL.PRICER, 10, 2)) END AS SALES_PRICE, 
                    CASE WHEN (dbo.MTREXTRA.BOOL02 = 1 AND CHARINDEX('/' + dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1NAME + '/', dbo.MTREXTRA.VARCHAR01 COLLATE Greek_CI_AS) > 0) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS ALLOW_BACKORDER
                FROM 
                    dbo.MTRL 
                INNER JOIN
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF ON dbo.MTRL.MTRL = dbo.CCCMLFINF.MTRL 
                INNER JOIN
                    dbo.MTREXTRA ON dbo.MTRL.MTRL = dbo.MTREXTRA.MTRL 
                INNER JOIN
                    dbo.CDIMLINES ON dbo.CCCMLFINF.COMPANY = dbo.CDIMLINES.COMPANY AND dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1 = dbo.CDIMLINES.CDIM AND dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIMLINES1 = dbo.CDIMLINES.CDIMLINES 
                WHERE 
                    dbo.MTRL.COMPANY = 2000 AND dbo.MTREXTRA.BOOL01 = 1 AND PRODUCTSTABLE.MTRL = dbo.MTRL.MTRL
                GROUP BY 
                    dbo.MTRL.CODE2, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1NAME, 
                    dbo.MTRL.PRICEW, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.FISCPRD, 
                    dbo.CDIMLINES.NAME1, 
                    dbo.MTRL.MTRL, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIM1, 
                    dbo.CCCMLFINF.CDIMLINES1, 
                    dbo.MTRL.PRICER, 
                    dbo.MTREXTRA.BOOL02, 
                    dbo.MTREXTRA.VARCHAR01, 
                    dbo.MTREXTRA.VARCHAR02, 
                    dbo.MTREXTRA.VARCHAR03
                FOR XML PATH ('Variation'), TYPE, ROOT ('Variations')
            ) AS Variations
        FROM 
            dbo.MTRL AS PRODUCTSTABLE 
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.MTRSEASON ON PRODUCTSTABLE.COMPANY = dbo.MTRSEASON.COMPANY AND PRODUCTSTABLE.MTRSEASON = dbo.MTRSEASON.MTRSEASON 
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.MTRMARK ON PRODUCTSTABLE.MTRMARK = dbo.MTRMARK.MTRMARK AND PRODUCTSTABLE.COMPANY = dbo.MTRMARK.COMPANY AND PRODUCTSTABLE.SODTYPE = dbo.MTRMARK.SODTYPE 
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.MTRMODEL ON PRODUCTSTABLE.MTRMODEL = dbo.MTRMODEL.MTRMODEL AND PRODUCTSTABLE.COMPANY = dbo.MTRMODEL.COMPANY AND PRODUCTSTABLE.SODTYPE = dbo.MTRMODEL.SODTYPE 
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.MTREXTRA ON PRODUCTSTABLE.MTRL = dbo.MTREXTRA.MTRL  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.utbl01 ON dbo.MTREXTRA.UTBL01 = dbo.UTBL01.UTBL01 AND dbo.utbl01.COMPANY = 2000
        WHERE 
            PRODUCTSTABLE.COMPANY = 2000 AND dbo.MTREXTRA.BOOL01 = 1 AND DATEDIFF(minute, PRODUCTSTABLE.UPDDATE, SYSDATETIME()) < 60
        FOR XML PATH('Product'), TYPE
    )
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Products');

GO

:XML OFF

My SQLCMD Invocation command is:
SQLCMD -U user -P password -S USER-PC\SOFTONE -i \QRS\qxml.SQL -o \QRS\products_update.xml

a sample xml output with errors from sqlcmd is:
<Products><Product><SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</SKU><PRODUCT_NAME>Replay Slides GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665 – Camo Black</PRODUCT_NAME><BRAND>REPLAY</BRAND><GENDER>ΑΝΔΡΑΣ</GENDER><SEASON>SS24</SEASON><COLOR>ΠΑΡΑΛΛΑΓΗ</COLOR><SOFT1ID>028036</SOFT1ID><Variations><Variations><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665-41</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>41</SIZE><STOCK>0</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>14</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665-42</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>42</SIZE><STOCK>2</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>16</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665-43</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>43</SIZE><STOCK>3</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>18</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665-44</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>44</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>20</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665-45</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>45</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>22</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>GMF1A.
002.C0050T.1665-46</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>46</SIZE><STOCK>0</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>39.00</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>GMF1A.002.C0050T.1665</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38689</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>24</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>31.00</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation></Variations></Variations></Product><Product><SKU>560846C</SKU><PRODUCT_NAME>Converse Chuck Taylor All Star Lift Hi Παπούτσια 560846C – White</PRODUCT_NAME><BRAND>CONVERSE</BRAND><GENDER>ΓΥΝΑΙΚΑ</GENDER><SEASON>SS24</SEASON><COLOR>ΛΕΥΚΟ</COLOR><SOFT1ID>028225</SOFT1ID><Variations><Variations><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-36.5</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>36.5</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>5</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-37</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>37</SIZE><STOCK>0</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>6</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-37.5</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>37.5</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>7</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-38</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>38</SIZE><STOCK>0</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>8</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-39</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>39</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PAREN
T_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>10</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-39.5</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>39.5</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>11</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-40</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>40</SIZE><STOCK>0</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>12</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation><Variation><VARIATION_SKU>560846C-41</VARIATION_SKU><SIZE>41</SIZE><STOCK>1</STOCK><REGULAR_PRICE>89.90</REGULAR_PRICE><PARENT_SKU>560846C</PARENT_SKU><CDIM>size-shoes</CDIM><MTRLID>38878</MTRLID><CDIM1>1003</CDIM1><LINENUM1>14</LINENUM1><SALES_PRICE>62.90</SALES_PRICE><ALLOW_BACKORDER>no</ALLOW_BACKORDER></Variation></Variations></Variations></Product></Products>

I have tried using the -y0 flag with no solution
Any ideas why I have different output between SQL Server Management Studio and sqlcmd?

More likely the version of sqlcmd is why it's behaving differently. CAn you provide us with an actual [mre]?

Couple of side notes: 3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated and should be avoided. Alias your objects and qualify your columns. Also the documentation states: "The GO command shouldn't appear before the :XML OFF command is issued, because the :XML OFF command switches sqlcmd back to row-oriented output."

Might as well mention that DATEDIFF(minute, PRODUCTSTABLE.UPDDATE, SYSDATETIME()) < 60 isn't SARGable; don't get the difference in time between a column and SYSDATETIME, check if the value of of the column is greater than the value of SYSDATETIME: PRODUCTSTABLE.UPDDATE > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, SYSDATETIME()).

Can you explain what kind of issue the xml file has? is it just clipped on 4k chars or what? Btw, why not add TYPE to the FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Products') declaration?

@ThomA Adding the GO command after :XML OFF creates a very corrupted and short xml. Not all data are exported. Am i missing something else, maybe in the way I invoke SQLCMD? I've just the naming of columns based on your suggestions, but the problem was not resolved.

@siggemannen The issue is that the output xml file has validation errors, For example: The element type "PARENT_SKU" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "". I haved edited my initial question to include a sample xml output.

Does it help adding TYPE thing?

@siggemannen it didnt help

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46153/sqlcmd-exporting-16-5-million-rows

On a side note, you can merge the ROOT() into the inner subquery and remove the outer subquery. Anyway, have you considered using Invoke-DbaQuery from DbaTools Powershell module?

XML wraps at 2033 characters? What version is reported by sqlcmd -?

Ended up using bcp with success, as suggested by the post in @YitzhakKhabinsky comment
